# Undefined index: Array, when the index is defined

Tags: php, arrays

This is making me crazy, because I need E_ALL turned on for other reasons. I can't get rid of this bug.

Here is my function:

```
public static function getFileCatsString($categories)
{
    if (empty($categories)) {
        return '';
    }
    $cats = self::getFileCats();

    $file_cats_string = '';
    $categories_array = explode(',',$categories);
    foreach($categories_array as $k=>$category_id) {
        $file_cats_string.=$cats[$category_id].', ';
    }
    $file_cats_string = rtrim($file_cats_string, ', ');
    return($file_cats_string);
}
```

Categories are stored in keyed array: [id]=>[string]

$categories that gets passed is a string of category_ids (long story as to why that is)

the getFileCats() method gets a list of all available categories.

So we explode the commad list to create an array, and then we loop through that array. I simply want to create, a string of category labels when I'm given a string of category ids. PHP returns this warning:

> Notice: Undefined index: Array in Documents.php on line 40

Line 40 is:

> ```
>       $file_cats_string.=$cats[$category_id].', ';
> ```

So obviously the undefined index is $cats[$category_id]. But here's where it gets weird.

If I use a die() statement and echo out $cats[$category_id] I indeed get a string, not an array.

By the way, here is the output of each of the three key pieces of data with a die() statement put at the top of the foreach loop.

$categories_array:

> Array ( [0] => 2 )

$cats:

> Array ( [9] => Category 19 [8] => Category 8 [7] => Category 7 [6] => Another String I Changed For Privacy [5] => AED Sales [4] => Preceptor Folder [3] => Education Brochures [2] => Forms [1] => Guidelines and Policies )

$cats[$category_id]

> Forms

$category_id

> 2

It gets weirder though. It says that the index is an array (which would indeed be a problem), so I tried putting:

```
        if (is_array($category_id)) {
            die(print_r($categories_array, true) . '<br />' . print_r($cats, true) . '<br />' . $cats[$category_id] . '<br />' . $category_id);
        }
```

to see if I could identify a piece of defending data, but it never dies. So what in the heck is going on?! (I have a sneaky suspicion that the answer is going to be forehead-slappingly simple.)

Comment: Try `var_dump($cats, $categories_array);` and check what the data actually is you deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is easier to understand knowing the fact that converting *any* array in PHP to a string results in the string:

```
"Array"
```

(this is also outlined in [Type Juggling](http://php.net/language.types.type-juggling) in the PHP manual)

Exactly that happens in line 40:

```
$file_cats_string .= $cats[$category_id] . ', ';
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The variable `$category_id` at that point is an array. Fix that. Valid array indexes/keys are integer numbers or strings but not arrays.

Comment: AHA! Okay, so the problem was, indeed with the data, but I wasn't looking at it the right way. I was getting thrown off by the presence of the "Array." I was testing for the value was an array (using is_array()), but the string was literally "Array" because some of the entries in the database are actually being stored as "Array," due to a bug somewhere else in the program.  So simple!

Comment: Okay, then it's the same cause but at a different location. You "stored" the bug into the database quasi. Those things are complicated to track, indeed.

Comment: BTW, to fix the problem with the bad data, I used: `if (!empty($cats[$category_id])){ $file_cats_string.= $cats[$category_id].', ';}`. It's like I said. Forehead-slappingly simple.

Answer (score 0):

In a `foreach` loop, the syntax `foreach($categories_array as $k=>$category_id) {` means, `$k` is the `key` and `$category_id` is the `value` per index/key. Hence, the array doesn't have a value with one of its value as index, that's why the error says *undefined index*.

Since `$category_id` is NOT an array, and its got a value 2, it doesnt pass the check of `if (is_array($category_id))`

Comment: The foreach loop is set up correctly. This is not the problem.

Comment: I didn't say the problem was the foreach, its just about understanding the syntax of it, and using key/value pairs accordingly.

Comment: See the accepted answer and comments. Your solution is what I initially thought, too, but the problem was that the word key "Array" was literally in the data-- it was a problem with bad data, not with a bad foreach loop (you can see in the comments that the foreach loop was set up correctly, and verified).